# Delete old machine from Samba

Tags: samba

I'm wondering is there a way to delete old machines from Samba?

I'd like to search all computers that hasn't had activity for longer than 3 months and have it removed from the domain controller.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this. You'll need to do this by logging at a higher-level, parsing the log file and writing a script to remove computers based on this log.